# Inflate Multiple Layouts at Once in ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I want a divider in my ListView when the days are different, so I'm using the code below to attempt to do that.

The problem with this is, in the getView() for the case of `TYPE_SEPARATOR`, I cannot inflate both the `chatheader` and `list_right_chat` or `list_left_chat` layout because it only returns the last view. How can I add both the divider (header) and the normal layout without directly adding the header into the List that is passed to the ListView?

Code:

```
public class ChatListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Message> {
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public ChatListAdapter(Context context, List<Message> items) {
    super(context, 0, items);
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return RowType.values().length;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    //Check Dates
    DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.getDefault();
    DateTime now = new DateTime( timeZone );
    Interval today = new Interval( now.withTimeAtStartOfDay(), now.plusDays(1).withTimeAtStartOfDay() );
    MutableDateTime epoch = new MutableDateTime();
    epoch.setDate(getItem(position).getEpochTime()); //Set to Epoch time
    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( epoch );
    boolean messageHappenedToday = today.contains( dateTime );

    if(position == 0)
    {
        if(messageHappenedToday)
            return TYPE_MESSAGE_ITEM;

        return TYPE_SEPARATOR;
    }
    else
    {
        //Check if current message is the same date as the last message.
        //Last message
        epoch.setDate(getItem(position - 1).getEpochTime()); //Set to Epoch time
        DateTime dateTimeLastMessage = new DateTime( epoch );
        Interval oneDayLastMessage = new Interval( dateTimeLastMessage.withTimeAtStartOfDay(), dateTimeLastMessage.plusDays(1).withTimeAtStartOfDay() );

        //Current message
        MutableDateTime epochCurrentMessage = new MutableDateTime();
        epochCurrentMessage.setDate(getItem(position).getEpochTime());
        DateTime dateTimeCurrentMessage = new DateTime(epochCurrentMessage);
        boolean lastMessageHappenedToday = oneDayLastMessage.contains( dateTimeCurrentMessage );

        if(lastMessageHappenedToday)
            return TYPE_MESSAGE_ITEM;
    }
    return TYPE_SEPARATOR;
}

private static final int TYPE_MESSAGE_ITEM = 0;
private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)  {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    int rowType = getItemViewType(position);
    View View;
    if (convertView == null) {
        Log.i("Cascade", "4: " + getItem(position).getFromName());

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        switch (rowType) {
            case TYPE_MESSAGE_ITEM:
                if(getItem(position).getSelf())
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_right_chat, null);
                else
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_left_chat, null);
                holder.View = getItem(position).getView(TYPE_MESSAGE_ITEM, mInflater, convertView);
                break;
            case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.chatheader, null);
                holder.View = getItem(position).getView(TYPE_SEPARATOR, mInflater, convertView);


                if(getItem(position).getSelf())
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_right_chat, null);
                else
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_left_chat, null);
                holder.View = getItem(position).getView(TYPE_MESSAGE_ITEM, mInflater, convertView);
                break;
        }
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    return convertView;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public  View View; }
}
```

I could always add the header to both of my layouts with `View.GONE` and make it visible when needed, but that seems kind of 'hacky'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything bad in including the header in both of your layouts.

Expecially, if it's possible in your case, I'd use a RecyclerView together with [Data Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) for displaying the data, and just few lines of code to decide whether display the header or not.

Answer (score -1):

You are adding Table Row into table so use TableLayout.LayoutParams instead of LinearLayout.LayoutParams.As we use LayoutParam according to parent in which we are going to add

```
            TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.TableLayout1);

        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams trparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tr.setLayoutParams(trparams);

        cg[i] = new EditText(this);
        weight[i] = new EditText(this);
        cg[i].setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
        weight[i].setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);

        //Here's where it goes wrong. By adding fieldparams, the text field doesn't even get generated.
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams fieldparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(10, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);
        tr.addView(cg[i], fieldparams);
        tr.addView(weight[i], fieldparams);

        table.addView(tr);
```

Comment: I'm not using a Table, and you can't use addView() in a ListView.